# how can I get list of network active connections ( pocess name, ID, PID, stat,TCp or UDP...)and write them to XML file in java

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I want to get all network active connections, with detail of their process name, `PID number, tcp or udp, stat (listen, connect..) local Ip address` and `remote ID address` of them, 
( something like when you run command : `netstat f`  on linux bash)
and then write them to a `XML file`, 
any one know how should I do this? which functions in java do these tasks.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: there are no functions in java which do this task.  in general, doing "native operating system" tasks like this is not going to be supported directly in java.  one option is to run one of these tools and parse the output.

Comment: @jtahlborn Have you heard about function:`GetTcp(); GetProcess(), GetNetworkinfo()` and....` in java? I think java.net.networkinterface package contain these functions , ( not sure about package name) but I saw them in java, my problem is that I dont know how to use these functions.!!!

Comment: i've heard of lots of things, and yes, i'm aware you can enumerate the network interfaces in java.  what does this have to do with your question?

Answer (score 0):

There's no java library/APi to do that.
But you can do it calling the OS service
for example in windows :
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;

```
public class TCPConnections
{
public static void main(String[] args){
try{
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("netstat","-a","-n","-o");
Process process = pb.start();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
String line;
while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
System.out.println(line);
}
br.close();
}catch(Exception e){
throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
 }
}
```

hope it helps